# parse multipe types of logs for Fortimail with LogStash

Tags: filter, logstash

I would like to know if it's possible to parse several types of logs for the same logs source.
For example, I have two different logs for two different types :

1. type = statistics :

   date=2012-07-16 time=12:22:56 device_id=FE100C3909600504 log_id=0200001075 type=statistics
   pri=information session_id="q6GJMuPu003642-q6GJMuPv003642" client_name="[172.20.140.94]"
   dst_ip="172.20.140.92" from="user@external.lab" to="user5@external.lab" subject="" mailer="mta" 
   resolved="OK" direction="in" virus="" disposition="Reject" classifier="Recipient Verification"
   message_length="188"
2. type = spam

   date=2012-07-16 time=12:22:56 device_id=FE100C3909600504 log_id=0300001075 type=spam 
   pri=information session_id="q6GJMuPu003642-q6GJMuPv003642" client_name="[172.20.140.94]" 
   dst_ip="172.20.140.92" from="user@external.lab" to="user5@external.lab" subject="" msg="
   ... User unknown"

In the filter (logstash), how can I do multiple regex for each type for logs in Fortimail ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter

```
filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    event['type'] = event['message'].split('type=')[1].split(' ')[0]
            "
    }
    if [type] == "statistics" {
         grok {
              //  parsing statistics logs
         }
    }

    if [type] == "spam" {
         grok {
              //  parsing spam logs
         }
    }
}
```

First, Get the `type` of the logs, then use condition `if` to parse different type of logs.

Hope this can help you. :)